How to visualise localization of a module or module of fractions?
What I understood in the localization or ring of fractions of a ring is that given a ring $R$ and a subset $S$ (multiplicatively closed) we want to construct some ring $R^*$ and ring homomorphism from $R$ to $R^*$, such that the image of $S$ consists of units (invertible elements) in $R^*$ and further we want $R^*$ to be the 'best possible'.
However, I can not visualize the module of fractions. I am aware of the construction of a module of fractions by defining the equivalence relation on $M \times S$ and taking the collection of equivalence classes. I also know $S^{-1}M \cong M ⊗  S^{-1}R$. But in this way also I can not think that what is the 'better' structure is there in $S^{-1}M$ as $S^{-1}R$ module than $M$ as an $R$ module.

Localisation at $S$ allows you to kill $S$-torsion, that is, if $\alpha\in S^{-1} M$ is such that there is an  element $s\in S$ satisfying $s\cdot \alpha=0$, then $\alpha=0$.

Regarding the usefulness: If $M$ is - for example - a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, and we consider $S = \mathbb{Z}\backslash0$, then $S^{-1}M = M \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ suddenly is a $\mathbb{Q}$-module, i.e. a vector space. In particular it now has a base.

Please don't use comments for posting answers. This is against the site policy how comments and answers work.
